# Copy string in MASM & reverse output using indirect addressing

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

The following program should take string input, isolate each character in the string and print the output in reverse order using indirect addressing. The output I get is an identical repeat of the original string. The output should be in reverse.

**** U P D A T E ****
Michael & ecm, I took your advice. Now when I check memory location &copyStrg in the debugger I can see the string in reverse order as it should be. However, I can't get it to print. There is something wrong with my print statement in lines 54 & 55.

**** U P D A T E **** Fixed!!!

```
'''
13      .data
14      msg         BYTE    "Enter a string:", 13, 10, 0
15      strg        BYTE    21 DUP(?)
16      copyStrg    BYTE    SIZEOF strg DUP(?)
17      i           DWORD   ?
18      j           DWORD   ?
19
20      .code
21      main        PROC                        ; Start
22
23          lea     EDX, Msg                    ; Print "Enter a string"
24          call    WriteString
25                      
26          mov     ECX, SIZEOF strg            ; Input strg
27          lea     EDX, strg
28          call    ReadString
29          mov     i, EAX                      ; i = size(strg) 
30          mov     j, 0                        ; j = 0
31          mov     ESI, i                      ; copyStrg[i] = 0
32          mov     copyStrg[ESI], 0
33          
34      
35      lup:                                    ; WHILE i > 0
36          cmp     i, 0                
37          jng     endLup              
38
39          mov     EAX, i                      ;    i--
40          dec     EAX
41          mov     i, EAX
42      
43          mov     ESI, i                      ;    copyStrg[j] = strg[i]
44          mov     EDI, j
45          mov     AL, strg[ESI]
46          mov     copyStrg[EDI], AL
47
48          mov     EBX, j                      ;    j++
49          inc     EBX
50          mov     j, EBX
51          jmp     lup
52   endLup:                                    ; ENDWHILE
53      
54          mov     EDX, OFFSET copyStrg        ; Print copyStrg
55          call    WriteString
56
57          call    CRLF
58          exit                                ; Stop

'''
```

Comment: `copyStrg[j] = strg[i]` part is very wrong. You want `mov esi, i` then `mov edi, j` then `mov al, strg[esi]` then `mov copyStrg[edi], al`. Not the only problem though.

Comment: What's the point of `mov AL, copyStrg[EDI]` `mov copyStrg[EDI], AL` ?

Comment: `copyStrg[i] = 0` part should read `mov byte ptr copyStrg[eax], 0`

Comment: You also did not initialise `j`. The `.data` section with a `?` likely does the right thing by accident but you should explicitly initialise `j` to zero. (Something your pseudo code does not show either.)

Comment: It's also not clear what `EDI`'s role in the `lup` loop is. On the first iteration its value will be 0, but then you overwrite it with `j` which at that point contains `i-1`.

Comment: The `i` and `j` variables seem kind of pointless anyway, since you could probably keep everything in registers.

Comment: Forget about `i` and `j`, as @Michael says. Let `ESI` point to the first byte of `strg` and `EDI` point to the last byte of `copyStrg`. Then in the `lup:` load a character from `[ESI]`, store it to `[EDI]`, increment `ESI`, decrement `EDI` and repeat.

Comment: Thank you all for your advice!  I got it to work after I took your suggestions and then made the final adjustment to the output statement on lines 54 & 55.  I'm just a CS student and I have to follow the pseudocode which lists 'i' and 'j' as variables. If I don't follow the pseudocode I lose points.

Comment: Then keep `i` and `j` in registers and use addressing modes like `[edi + edx]` and `[edi + ecx]` for 2 different offsets into the same array which EDI points to.  (Or use a static array like `[strg + edx]` or whatever.)  You still don't want to keep `i` and `j` in memory; that's horrible and totally inconvenient because you can't use them as array indices until you load them into registers.  C local variables can be mapped to registers or stack space, not asm labels.  Asm labels are like global variables or `static int i;`.